# Как получить объект из json на языке c#

Tags: c#, json, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Требовалось вывести на datagridview список всех заявок (из json) вывел я их с помощью Newthonjson. создал список и передал его как ресурс для datagridview.
проблема в том что ответ состоит из объекта в котором есть другой объект выглядит примерно так:

```
[
{
    "orderedBy": {
        "name": "Имя заказчика",
        "_id": "60a61e6656403833a40f73ee"
    },
    "takenBy": {
        "name": "Имя принявшего заказ",
        "_id": "60a7b663288d253d401592b0"
    },
    "takenAt": "2021-05-21",
    "_id": "60a7b24e1f32040990c37572",
    "status": "in progress",
    "description": "test order",
    "ordered_At": "2021-05-21",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "orderedBy": {
        "name": "Имя",
        "_id": "60a61e6656403833a40f73ee"
    },
    "takenAt": null,
    "_id": "60a7b2892d3d3c2c500abaf0",
    "description": "test order",
    "status": "created",
    "ordered_At": "2021-05-21",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "orderedBy": {
        "name": "Имя",
        "_id": "60a61e6656403833a40f73ee"
    },
    "takenAt": null,
    "_id": "60a7b28e2d3d3c2c500abaf1",
    "description": "test order2",
    "status": "created",
    "ordered_At": "2021-05-21",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "orderedBy": {
        "name": "Имя",
        "_id": "60a61e6656403833a40f73ee"
    },
    "takenBy": {
        "name": "Имя",
        "_id": "60a7b663288d253d401592b0"
    },
    "takenAt": "2021-05-21",
    "_id": "60a7b2922d3d3c2c500abaf2",
    "description": "test order3",
    "status": "done",
    "ordered_At": "2021-05-21T13:16:02.411Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "orderedBy": {
        "name": "Имя",
        "_id": "60a61e6656403833a40f73ee"
    },
    "takenAt": null,
    "_id": "60a88ffbc9b24a0015db80ef",
    "description": "this is description of order",
    "status": "created",
    "ordered_At": "2021-05-22",
    "__v": 0
}
```

]

Заполняю datagrid таким способом:

```
private void FillDatagrvw(string json)
    {
        dynamic job= new List<OrderResponse>();
        
        try
        {
            job = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderResponse>>(json);
           
        }
        catch (Exception ext){
            MessageBox.Show(ext.ToString());
        }
        if (job != null)
        {
            
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = job;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        }
    }
```

Поля класса OrderResponse:

```
public class OrderResponse { 
    public OrderBy orderedBy { get; set; }
    public TakenBy takenBy { get; set; }
    public string ordered_At { get; set; }
    public string takenAt { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Помогите получить значения orderedBy и takenBy. Заранее спасибо

Comment: При чем тут Java? Где вы увидели "массив в массиве"? Массив, это `[ ... ]`, у вас он один. Далее, почему `dynamic job=`? Почему `OrderBy` и `TakenBy` это отдельные классы, если свойства у них одинаковые? Да и вообще, в чем проблемы? У вас должно все работать.

Comment: Ерундой не страдайте, вы уже сделали класс, в который все десериализуется, зачем вам "динамика"? Уберите `dynamic` и используйте класс как положено (`item.OrderBy.Name`)! (ответ на удалившийся коммент...)

Comment: Можете подробно описать ваш ответ?

Comment: А что тут отвечать то? Вы не знаете как обращаться к свойствам класса или что? Я просто не понимаю вашу проблему, в чем трудности написать `item.OrderBy.Name`?

Comment: Я передаю список в datagridview в котором значении этих полей отсутствуют

Comment: И что вы там увидеть собираетесь?

Comment: вместо этого выводится текст orderedBy и takenBy я понимаю что значения я могу получить orderedBy.name т.д но мне нужно все в один список отправить

Comment: Я понял о чем вы. я хотел узнать возможность сразу передать список не расписывая значения поля по одному

Comment: Тогда наверно надо делать акцент не на JSON и сериализации/десериализации, а на вывод свойств класса в `datagridview`, не думаете так? Зачем вот нам, людям, которые совершенно не знают вас и ваш проект знать что либо про JSON, про то что "на JAVA я мог...", про то что "объект в объекте", вот смысл этого, если вам надо лишь кастомную колонку?

Comment: Самое банальное решение, которое вы можете сделать - переопределить `ToString` (`public override string ToString() => Name;`) у `TakenBy` и `OrderBy` (это один объект, сделайте один класс, назовите его не знаю, `By` и используйте его), автогенерация должна будет вывести все как надо. Другим решением скорей всего будет отказ от автогенерации и созданием колонок самостоятельно.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Буду пробовать

Comment: Ваше решение мне подошло все сделал как подсказали в последнем комментарии. Очень благодарен

Comment: Метод `ToString` предназначен для разработчика (для отладки). Если у вас всё работает, то можете оставить способ с его переопределением, но по гайдам, для вывода информации конечному пользователю, лучше его не использовать. | См. [Customize Data Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-data-formatting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class OrderResponse
{
    public OrderBy orderedBy { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy_name => orderedBy.name;
    public string OrderBy_id => orderedBy._id;
    public TakenBy takenBy { get; set; }
    public string takenBy_name => takenBy.name;
    public string takenBy_id => takenBy._id;
    public string ordered_At { get; set; }
    public string takenAt { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```